# How to use a RecordType in an XSD Schema Definition in Android

Tags: android, xsd, schema, xsd-validation, oval

I have a test my_test which contains an object my_object and a state my_state. The test has one entity my_entity and three corresponding fields a,b and c. I need to display the data in record format combining all the three fields. Here is a sample of how I am thinking of doing it, but not sure whether it's correct.

```
<xsd:element name="abc" type="oval-def:EntityStateRecordType" minOccurs="0">
<xsd:annotation>
     <xsd:documentation></xsd:documentation>
     <xsd:appinfo>
       <sch:pattern id="android-def_mytest">
     <sch:rule context="android-def:my_state/android-def:abc">
     <sch:assert test="@datatype='record'"><sch:value-of select="../@id"/> - datatype               attribute for the value entity of a state must be 'record'</sch:assert>
     </sch:rule>
       </sch:pattern>
      </xsd:appinfo>
</xsd:annotation>

<xsd:unique name="UniqueFields">
     <xsd:selector xpath="./oval-def:field"/>
        <xsd:field xpath="@name"/>
</xsd:unique>
```

The problem with this method is, I cannot describe the fields inside xsd. Is there any other method to do so using RecordType? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where does the sch: prefixs come from? This is not xsd. appInfo is where vendors can markup the schema for their own purposes - this probably gets compiled into some kind of code.